# want to change Velocity template to other new technology give technology name and give differences also if possible?

Tags: velocity, template-engine

I want to change my product existing technology of email template in to new email template technology.So could you please suggest technology name and also the difference with velocity. We want less dependencies like no use of XML XSLT languages everything should be very less hectic and more easy to understand and write.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/). [There is a (old) discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459426/velocity-vs-freemarker) about how it is better than velocity.

Anyway, I will not recommend you to use Velocity. The last stable release was about 2010.