# Freemarker Vs Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, velocity, freemarker

I'm using angularjs for my application, which is so secure (similar like banking application),i have another option of using freemarker or velocity ..
whether it is best to go with angularjs or we can use freemarker or velocity. if so could you please explain. the backend service is spring boot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Freemarker` is just a templating engine, it's not a full front-end framework with 2 way data binding like `angularjs` is. Also, with `angular` it's very easy to build [Single Page Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) which have a very smooth user experience compared to traditional applications where you must reload the page every time the user navigates to another page. If you already know angular, it's the better choice. If you don't know angular, then freemarker is much faster to learn but not quite as powerful/good. Though I do quite like freemarker as a templating engine.

Comment: Is Velocity is better than Freemarker ?

Comment: I've never used `velocity` but there's a good thread on the subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459426/velocity-vs-freemarker)

Comment: Thank you Scott, I really got some idea